# row drag and drop bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I trie with bootstrap-table to include a sort order drag and drop on the the row.
But the system work just when I click on the table heading, if I change the sort order of the row it does not with the ajax.

I tried to remove the sort order inside the heading, I have the same problem.
Do you have any idea to resolve that ? Maybe there is a conflict ?

My table :

```
  <table
    id="table"
    data-toggle="table"
    data-icons-prefix="bi"
    data-icons="icons"
    data-sort-name="sort_order"
    data-sort-order="asc"
    data-toolbar="#toolbar"
    data-buttons-class="primary"
    data-show-toggle="true"
    data-show-columns="true"
    data-mobile-responsive="true"
    data-reorderable-rows="true">

    <thead class="dataTableHeadingRow">
      <tr>
        <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true"><?php echo $categories->getDef('table_heading_categories_products'); ?></th>
        <th data-field="status" data-sortable="true" class="text-center"><?php echo $categories->getDef('table_heading_status'); ?></th>
        <th data-field="last_modified" data-sortable="true" class="text-center"><?php echo $categories->getDef('table_heading_last_modified'); ?></th>
        <th data-field="sort_order" data-sortable="true" class="text-center"><?php echo $categories->getDef('table_heading_sort_order'); ?></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
       ......
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

About my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $table = $("#table");
  //data export
  $table.bootstrapTable({
    exportDataType: $(this).val(),
    exportTypes: ["json", "xml", "csv", "excel", "pdf"],
  });




  // Sorting
  $table.on("sort.bs.table", function(e, name, order) {
    var ids = $.map($table.bootstrapTable("getData"), function(row) {
      return row.id;
    });
    $.ajax({
      url:"ajax/categories_table_sort_order.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { ids: ids },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log("Order saved successfully!");
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error("Error saving order: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
    });
  });




  // checkbox remove
  $('body').on('click', '#button', function() {
    if (!window.confirm("Are you sure?")) return false;
  });
});
```

The librairies called

```
//Dependance for drag and drop
        $output .= '<script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/TableDnD/1.0.5/jquery.tablednd.min.js"></script>' . "\n";
//bootstrap table
        $output .= '<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>' . "\n";
//export
        $output .= '<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.4/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script>' . "\n";
        $output .= '<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/tableExport.min.js"></script>' . "\n";
//Row Reorder
        $output .= '<script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.21.4/extensions/reorder-rows/bootstrap-table-reorder-rows.min.js"></script>' . "\n";
//bootstrap table script
        $output .= '<script defer src="' . $this->link('Shop/ext/javascript/bootstrapTable/bootstrap_table_customisation.js') . '"></script>' . "\n";

echo $output;
```

Thank you